# Ocusdk ( Oculus SDK ) or Cbsdk ( Cardboard SDK ) for my VR APP?

Tags: oculus, google-cardboard, virtual-reality

I am new to VR applications design and development and need your expert opinion. Will Ocusdk work on google cardboard, after specially with a release of oculus mobile sdk ( which is used in samsung vr-gear) or cardboard only works with Cbsdk? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the license, you cannot use the oculus mobile sdk for cardboard apps.

> The Oculus Mobile SDK may not be used to interface with unapproved commercial virtual reality mobile or non-mobile products or hardware.

[link to the license](https://developer.oculus.com/licenses/license-3.2.1/)